# Grid cells with bullet points

Tags: extjs

I am trying to implement a ExtJS based grid where users would change column data or enter empty columns. Is there a way to show/enter contents as bullet points on ExtJS grid cell like we usually do in Excel?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle - https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/mpl

The Idea is to use [htmleditor](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.HtmlEditor) as the column editor in your grid. However, there'll be quite a lot of work involved in positioning and styling when the html editor opens up for editing.

The fiddle that I created contains just the editor with no styling so it doesn't open good. And when you try, try editing the first column in third row data.